# SF book where alien girls award medals for sexual prowess

Tags: story-identification, science-fiction-genre

I read this in the UK but it was forty plus years ago so the details are hazy. It could have been a novelette.

There are two Earthmen on some alien planet, I can't remember what their mission was. The inhabitants are very similar to humanity but possibly longer legs and very slender.

The females give some kind of medallions out to males if a satisfactory sexual coupling takes place, the more a male has, the higher his social status. Because the Earthmen have a sturdier build than the native males they score much  higher and are very successful.

One Earthmen develops his own score system, so instead (for example) of having several dozen silver medals pinned to his chest he has a gold that's worth ten of the silvers - please note that I'm not cognisant on these specific colours, I'm just trying to recall the actuality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a John Boyd novel, possibly *[The Rakehells of Heaven](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/768450.The_Rakehells_of_Heaven)* (1969).

> "The girl, Harla, wishes for Red, with the maple-leaf award, to tutor her in Earth biology."
> Red reached for the translator, beating me to the button by a hair. "In honor of the girl with green eyes, the greatest wish of my heart is to tutor her in Earth biology."
> Before the machine could emit the translation, I was pressing the "input"  button and feeding it a question: "What does the maple-leaf award signify?"
> They listened and Hedrik spoke again into his translator, turned and
> stepped on the platform. As Harla hoisted the machine aboard, its answer came loud and clear, branding Red O'Hara an adulterer and the girl with the aura of spirituality a harlot.
> "Excellence in fornication."

"Two Earthmen on an alien planet with lots of sex" would do for a description for several of his books.

Comment: If you want to refresh your memories of the book and improve your answer, it can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/rakehellsofheave0000boyd_q9h7

Comment: Yes! That's it - "Rakehells of Heaven" I've got a copy now and the medals are actually mini maple leaf symbols, the Earthman known as Red introduces the Gold ones to leave space on his tunic

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a short quote.

Comment: Wow, Harla the harlot, and Red O'Hara branded an adulterer (with a scarlet letter, no doubt). Subtle Boyd was not.

Comment: @Adamant I've read two other Boyd novels: *Sex and the High Command* and *The Pollinators of Eden*. Both demonstrate Boyd's un-subtlety quite well. He had a good niche (oversexed stories told without explicit language) and he stuck to it.